# Run "+normal <leader>?" when starting vim on the command line

Tags: terminal, leader

**Context**

- vimrc:

  - maps `<leader>` to `,`
  - maps `',?'` to an action

From a terminal, `vim '+normal ,?'` runs the action just fine.

**Problem**

Run the same terminal command without hardcoding the   character in the terminal command.

**Failed solutions (so far)**

- `vim "+normal <leader>?"` does not execute the action
- `vim :exe "+normal \<leader>?"` does not execute the action (yet `vim :exe "+normal ,?"` works)

Answer (score 1):

You can use the value of the `mapleader` global variable (see `:help mapleader`) like this

```
vim +'execute "normal "..g:mapleader.."?"'
```

See `:help :execute` how this will create a command. It also explains how `..` are used for string concatenation without inserting whitespace.

You don't show what action you map `<leader>?` to but chances are it's more concise than the expression above. You might want to create a function or command you can call from the command line *and* map to `<leader>?`.

Your `vimrc` would contain these lines:

```
command MyAction " perform the action

nnoremap <leader>? <Cmd>MyAction<CR>
```

And this is how it would be called from the shell:

```bash
vim +MyAction
```

Comment: "chances are it's more concise than the expression above" agreed

Comment: Even better: make it an Ex command called `:Action` and call it with `$ vim +Action`. I have `:EV` for "edit `vimrc`", which I use quite often as `$ vim +EV`. Also, the value of `g:mapleader` can change between uses of `<Leader>` so there is no "safe" way to query it. One more reason for not using that half-assed feature.

Comment: @romainl your earlier comment was so *agreeable* I started to feel concerned about your well-being. Now I'm very relieved to see you're your true self again. Thank you for your suggestion on using a command. I modified my answer accordingly. The pitfall of `mapleader` changing is always there. This answer doesn't make it any more likely to happen. In my experience, it works as long as you don't try to be clever.